# NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsstring

I have been stuck with this for a while and don't seem to get around this.

I am trying to read the contents of an URL as a string from an URL, But i get a weird

> Error -> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)"

My code :

```
fetchedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.example.com/iphone"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];                                     
    NSLog(@"%@",fetchedString);

    // if there is something wrong with the URL 
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error -> %@", error);
        return ;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried using getting as NSData as well, but I get null back.

Comment: try adding `http://` for the URL part.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the URL is missing the scheme: "http://".

"Error -> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256"

For the error code check the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html):

NSError codes in the Cocoa error domain.

```
NSFileReadUnknownError = 256,
```

`NSFileReadUnknownError`
"Read error, reason unknown"

Not that the error definition is very helpful. :-)

Also do not check if `error` is `nil` to determine if there is an error, check the return value for `nil`. `error` is not guaranteed to be `nil` on successful execution.

Comment: Thanks for your message. But I found something more interesting 
I have the following code.
    NSURL *serverUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *stringFromStream = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:serverUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"string is %@ error is %@", stringFromStream, error);
    
I got following error
string is (null) error is Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)" UserInfo=0x6a36c60 {NSURL=http://google.com, NSStringEncoding=4}

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem accessing files located on my device.  I followed [NSURL isFileURL always returns NO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557191/nsurl-isfileurl-always-returns-no/13557216#13557216)
and used [NSURL fileURLWithPath] instead of [NSURL URLWithString] - this worked!

Answer (score 4):

I got this error (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256) as soon as our ssl certificate expired. that may not help you but could help someone else.

Answer (score 3):

## Sandboxing

If you're using sandboxing in your app, you might want to check that **`com.apple.security.network.client`** is set to **`YES`**. It's in the the **General** tab of your Target in Xcode 5 under

*Network: Outgoing Connections (Client)*

Also be aware that if you see a code `257` when trying to reach a `file:///` url, that's also probably because of sandboxing, but this time rather the *File Access* part. Because I didn't want to open it to anything else than `com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write'

*User selected files*

I preferred to use [A Dead Simple Fileserver](http://stoneship.org/software/adsf/) and use `http://localhost:3000` when in Debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

More reasons that might be causing this specific error:

1. SSL is misconfigured on the server
2. The server redirects (301) the http URL to https (see #1)
3. [App transport security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http) also uses this code for blocked requests.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. The above marked answer is perfect. But in my case, I had the "http://" in the url but had to add the port number in the url request since there is a service running on a specific port that is actually responding to your request. 
    `@"http://example.com:8084/yyy.zzz"`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, the above solution didn't work for me, in my case i was calling **dataWithContentsOfURL** from within a **UNNotificationServiceExtension** so i had to update the info.plist file of the **UNNotificationServiceExtension** with the app transport security entries.

Answer (score 0):

I had the error because a local file could not be found although it was referenced inside of the project file and its working directory.

Basically, I forgot to check its `Target Membership`.

Make sure to check this in Xcode's inspector (right pane) when tapping on the file inside of the Project Navigator (left pane):

[image: Image showing checked Target Membership checkbox in Xcode]