# NSURL isFileURL always returns NO

Tags: ios, filesystems, nsurl, nsfilemanager, avcapturemoviefileoutput

Can someone explain to me why the following code:

```
NSString* filePathString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];

NSLog(@"%i", [[NSURL URLWithString:filePathString] isFileURL]);
NSLog(@"%@", filePathString);
```

outputs:

0

"/var/mobile/Applications/28ADFC19-874C-4304-94B5-F6441CAE9FAD/Documents"

This means that this url isn't a file URL. Obviously, it is.

---

**Background:**

I'm trying to use an AVCaptureMovieFileOutput to write a movie recording to a file, but the file url I'm proving gives the error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:] - Cannot record to URL /var/mobile/Applications/28ADFC19-874C-4304-94B5-F6441CAE9FAD/Documents/media/CrKNjNhe9so2LRnD9iHK.mov because it is not a file URL.'

That looks like a file URL to me, just like the original example. What gives?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want to create an `NSURL` from a file path, you must use `NSURL fileURLWithPath:`. The use of `URLWithString` assumes the string is a non-file URL.

An `NSURL` is a file URL only if it begins with `file://`.