# How do I get NSData from a video url?

Tags: ios, swift, video, nsdata

I'm trying to get video from a UIImagePicker and send it as data across my restkit API.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let videoURL = info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] as? NSURL

var movieData: NSData?
        do {
            movieData = try NSData(contentsOfURL: videoPath, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            movieData = nil
            return
        }

// Multipart Form Request for RestKit POST goes here

        imagePickerController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Getting the following error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “asset.MOV” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=B906AB1B-F311-47BA-8FE9-EE7AADDB7796&ext=MOV}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106087/nscocoaerrordomain-code-256)

Comment: `NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)`

Answer (score 6):

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
            let videoURL = info["UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"] as? NSURL
             do {
                let video = try NSData(contentsOfURL: videoPath, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
             } catch {
                print(error)
                return
             }
            imagePickerController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I handle video from Device:

```
@IBAction func addVideoFromDevice(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let mediaUI = UIImagePickerController()
    mediaUI.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
    mediaUI.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as NSString as String]
    mediaUI.allowsEditing = true
    mediaUI.delegate = self
    present(mediaUI, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
    if mediaType == kUTTypeMovie {
        let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL
        let avAsset = AVAsset(url: videoURL as URL) //>selected video
    } else{
        print("error @ mediaType-didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo")
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Hope it helps :)