# dataWithContentsOfURL doesn't work 20-30% of the time, what could be the reason?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

When running the following lines of code, I see this in the log: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “some_page” couldn’t be opened`

Here is the code:

```
NSError *downloadError = nil;
NSData *theJSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:s] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&downloadError];
NSLog(@"error : %@", downloadError);
```

**This happens only 20-30% of the time**

What could be the reason?
I found an answer where they say iOS doesn't support http, so I added NS app transport security. But anyway, it happens only sometimes.

**Update**:
I just found out that this is the cause:

```
if(! [[fullURL substringFromIndex:fullURL.length-1] isEqualToString:@"/"])
   s = [fullURL stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
```

why does it not work 20% of the time with the same url when I add the "/"?

Comment: [this might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10106824/1066828) [here is whole google search](https://www.google.com.kw/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enKW556KW556&q=NSCocoaErrorDomain+Code%3D256&oq=NSCocoaErrorDomain+Code%3D256&gs_l=serp.3..0l2j0i22i30k1l3.6948.8691.0.8939.2.2.0.0.0.0.223.409.0j1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.2.408...30i10k1.FEdUSupRN9E)

Comment: Is your URL string (s) always the same or you construct it dynamically each time ?

Comment: @BogdanFarca It's always the same, and the same one doesn't work 20% of the times

Comment: Are you sure the URL is always working, regardless of your app? Could you try it in a browser repeatedly and see if it's working in there ?

Comment: @BogdanFarca yes, but see the next update please.

Comment: Check before hand if `[NSURL URLWithString:s]` is not `nil`.

Comment: So, with the update it works 100% ?

Comment: Basically **never ever** load data from a remote URL with the synchronous method `dataWithContentsOfURL`. Use asynchronous `URLSession`

Comment: url is not null. with this update it works 100% of the time. but the question is still relevant, I would like to find an answer.

Comment: @wp42: Try to logs always `fullURL`, and try them in browser. Check if the one with `/` or `without` are working on web browser or with a POSTMAN-like.

Comment: @Larme of course they work